# Python Bottle: Can't connect to server or debug it

Tags: python, logging, server, httprequest, httpresponse

When I'm trying to run a server in this example I can see that it runs on the correct port. However, it is not possible to reach it externally (internal server error) nor to debug it in console through common methods (can't see any output).

I'm sure the port is available and the server runs. How to fix or debug this?

```
from bottle import run, post, request, response, get, route

@route('/<path>', method = 'GET')
def process(path):
    response.content_type = 'text/html'
    return 'Hello World GET'

@route('/<path>', method = 'POST')
def process(path):
    response.content_type = 'text/html'
    return 'Hello World POST'

run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this was setting `host='localhost'`, which made the server inaccessible from outside and I could use only `localhost` for access. Changing the declaration to `host='0.0.0.0'` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [@route](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.route) decorator does require a `path` variable which specifies the URL path.

Your code missed the `path` variable in the `@route` decorator.

It should work like

```
@route('/', method = 'GET')
def process(path):
    response.content_type = 'text/html'
    return 'Hello World POST'
```

Comment: I tried both with and without the `path` variable, but there seems to be something else causing this

Comment: Well, I copied your edited code and it works fine. I don't know why your code is not working in your env. Maybe you can try to change your environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you see this in the context of debugging using PyCharm, try this:

Go to Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Debugger.
In that dialog, you'll see a "Gevent compatible" checkbox. Not sure how it got unticked in the new project.

Tick that option and enjoy!

[source](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/615#issuecomment-294376069)